# Native 3d model capturing? And point cloud exporting?

Tags: 3d, kinect

I'm trying to capture objects in 3d with the azure Kinect and I was just wondering if it was possible to do it natively, and if so, how? But also, another one of my questions is can I export a certain data stream from the camera and if so, how? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Azure Kinect yet, but I'd assume it's SDK has something like Kinect Studio (which I used with Kinect 2.0). AFAIK there isn't any ready made official sample that this for you. My hunch is trying to generate and write pointclouds to disk while recording will be slow. I recommend recording raw depth data first, then processing a recording to pointclouds separately.

Having a quick glance at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kinect-dk/record-sensor-streams-file), you should be able to record the streams with the [Azure Kinect DK Recorder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kinect-dk/azure-kinect-recorder). This should allow you to record the raw data in near real-time.

Once you have your recordings, you can write a basic program to process each recorded frame, convert depth to point clouds as needed and save to file.

Doing a quick search I see few interesting results:

- the [Azure Kinect Sensor SDK fastpointcloud sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/tree/develop/examples/fastpointcloud) looks handy for converting to a point cloud (and exporting to PLY format)
- There's a [Azure Kinect Sensor SDK KinectFusion example](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Samples/tree/master/opencv-kinfu-samples) which could interesting to explore, though not for the faint of heart (given it requires OpenCV built from source with the `opencv-contrib` packages (`rgbd`) in particular)

I also recommend looking into [Open3D Azure Kinect Integration](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/Basic/azure_kinect.html). (It's reconstruction pipeline is pretty cool, and generating point clouds from RGBD sequencing and saving to PLY / PCD / etc. is trivial. Personally I found the Python API fast to protype with, but Open3D has a C++ API too)